# Makefile (with suffixes) in C

Tags: c, makefile

So I have three files:

```
log.c : defines all the functions
log.h : lists all the functions
main.c. : uses the functions
```

Now, both `log.c` and `main.c` have headers for `log.h`.

```
gcc log.c main.c
```

The above runs fine, no errors. However, when I try to make a Makefile following [this](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) tutorial, I have:

```
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS=-I

 log: main.o log.o
     $(CC) -o log main.o log.o -I
```

When I run `make`, this shows an error every time `main` called a function defined in `log.c`, saying "undefined reference to (function)".

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
-bash-4.2$ make
gcc -I   -c -o main.o main.c
/tmp/ccQOC7wH.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `getlog'
main.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `buildmsg'
main.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `savelog'
main.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `buildmsg'
main.c:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `buildmsg'
main.c:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `getlog'
main.c:(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `savelog'
main.c:(.text+0x247): undefined reference to `buildmsg'
main.c:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `getlog'
main.c:(.text+0x268): undefined reference to `savelog'
main.c:(.text+0x279): undefined reference to `clearlog'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please show the exact error. The above rule command is either not running or is giving an error that you are not showing. Because the `-I` option requires a value and `gcc` will not run successfully as shown.

Comment: Read carefully. The actual command in the tutorial has a `.` after the `-I` option: `-I.`

Comment: I included the full error message, and the -I. made no difference

Comment: Fix up the -I option. Though I don't agree with the tutorial in using the `-I` option like that. For headers in the same directory as the C source they should just be include as `#include "header.h"` and the compiler will automatically find it without the `-I.` option.

Comment: I did, it gives me the same error

Comment: I don't believe you. That is a link error. If you fix up  the `-I` then the `-c` option will come into play correctly and cause gcc to correctly compile only. That is, there will not be a link operation on that command and hence you cannot get that error. Please show *exact* output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran your makefile that had `-I` instead of `-I.`, you created an invalid  `main.o`.  You need to put the `-I.` back into `CFLAGS` and `rm *.o` from that directory.  Then it should make ok.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified an include directory for the `I` option, so during the compilation stage GCC actually interprets `-c` as an include directory, which cancels the compile-only flag, and then tries to link your program.

You don't need the include flag, you don't even need a recipe for linking because your file layout matches the builtin rules, your entire Makefile (assuming `cc` is a link to your default compiler) can simply be

```
log: log.o main.o
```

Comment: Interesting: classic versions of `make` would require a linking command, but GNU Make does not (somewhat to my surprise).  You should include: `main.o log.o: log.h` as well, in theory, but your minimal file gets the job done.  There are some distinct limits on that mechanism, but in context, it does work.